# local web development not working on OSX

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, webserver, dnsmasq, osx-server

I have DNSmasq setup properly to point any *.dev domains to localhost. My apache vhosts are all configured to the appropriate folders yet I am not getting any response from the local sites. I have been pulling my hair out and searching online for various answers without success. Just to point out that this setup worked previously and a High Sierra Security update just broke everything.

Here is my host config:

```
<Directory "/www">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/home/wwwroot"
  ServerName home.dev
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/wwwroot"
  ServerName sites.dev
  ServerAlias *.dev
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%-7+/wwwroot"
  ServerName xip
  ServerAlias *.xip.io
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

I just noticed that ping home.dev returns 127.0.0.1 but dig home.dev returns 127.0.53.53

And here is my DNS resolution:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 208.67.220.220
  if_index : 9 (en7)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

resolver #8
  domain   : local
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #9
  domain   : dev
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 208.67.220.220
  if_index : 9 (en7)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. dev domains seem to be official domains that you can register and therefore created a conflict in my DNS resolution causing it to point to 127.0.53.53 which is an IP usually attributed when a conflict arises. It means that *.dev had tried to resolve via my public DNS setting and via my localhost setting, creating a conflict. I switched my local development domain names over to *.test and everything worked straight away.